# Github - Commit error after renaming package in android application: LibGit2Sharp.LockedFileException: The index is locked

Tags: android, git, github

After renaming package of an android application, I am facing a commit error as follows:

> Showing user error Failed to create a new commit.
>   LibGit2Sharp.LockedFileException: The index is locked. This might be due to a concurrent or crashed process
>
> at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
>
> at LibGit2Sharp.Index.Replace(TreeChanges changes)
>
> at LibGit2Sharp.Index.Replace(Commit commit, IEnumerable`1 paths, ExplicitPathsOptions explicitPathsOptions)
>
> at LibGit2Sharp.Index.Replace(Commit commit)
>
> at GitHub.ExclusiveRepositoryConnection.<>c__DisplayClass13.b__10()
>
> at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Defer`1.Eval()
>
> at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Defer`1._.Run()

Renaming package caused changes in 1) almost entire files of the android application and also 2) folder names of Git repository.

Does anybody have the same issue? Or am I missing something?

Any input will be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Comment: can you check in the `.git` repository if there exists a file `index.lock`?

Comment: Hi Deborah, sure, I checked the .git repository and the file index.lock exists in the repository. Any instructions at this time?

Comment: Could you navigate to your git repository via the command line and try this:
On linux/unix/gitbash/cygwin, 
rm -f .git/index.lock

On Windows Command Prompt, try:

del .git\index.lock

Comment: It works Deborah! I will accept your answer if you post your answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @makeeasy. I'm glad it worked. I've posted a new answer to that effect. Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that there is already an `index.lock` file in the .got folder of your repository. Every time you create a commit, a check is made that this file does not already exist.

Fix this issue by running

On linux/unix/gitbash/cygwin,

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

On Windows Command Prompt, try:

```
del .git\index.lock
```

Comment: Saved another hours. Thanks a lot!